# JQuery - Keep the same event [mouseenter] in a nested element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an hover event in an element with a nested a icon.

The problem is when the cursor touch the `<i class="material-icons fav icons lov-icon lov-icon-color"> favorite</i>` element because that tigger the event `mouseout`

How to keep the same event in a nested element ?

```
$(".fav-btn").mouseout((event) => {
  let favButton = $(event.currentTarget);
  let favIcon = $(event.currentTarget.children[0]);
  console.log(favButton);
  if (favButton.hasClass('fav-btn-selected') && favIcon.hasClass('lov-icon-color-selected')) {
    favButton.removeClass('fav-btn-selected');
    favIcon.removeClass('lov-icon-color-selected');
    favButton.addClass('fav-btn');
    favIcon.addClass('lov-icon-color');
  }
});
$(".fav-btn").mouseenter((event) => {
  let favButton = $(event.currentTarget);
  let favIcon = $(event.currentTarget.children[0]);
  console.log(favIcon);

  if (favButton.hasClass('fav-btn') && favIcon.hasClass('lov-icon-color')) {
    favButton.removeClass('fav-btn');
    favIcon.removeClass('lov-icon-color');
    favButton.addClass('fav-btn-selected');
    favIcon.addClass('lov-icon-color-selected');
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4mLnckaw/3/

Comment: Use `mouseleave` instead of `mouseout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you can also use `hover` and `toggleClass` to do so.

Here's a demo:

```js
$(".fav-btn").hover((event => {
  let favButton = $(event.currentTarget);
  let favIcon = $(event.currentTarget.children[0]);
  favButton.toggleClass('fav-btn fav-btn-selected');
  favIcon.toggleClass('lov-icon-color lov-icon-color-selected');
}));
```

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50% !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50% !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -2px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.circle>.icons {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  /* 50% - 3/4 of icon height */
}

.fav-btn {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.msg-btn {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.lov-icon {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.msg-icon {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.lov-icon-color {
  color: red;
}

.msg-icon-color {
  color: green;
}

.fav-btn-selected {
  background-color: #b61825;
}

.msg-btn-selected {
  background-color: green;
}

.lov-icon-color-selected {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.msg-icon-color-selected {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<a href="">
  <div class="circle fav fav-btn m-2">
    <i class="material-icons fav icons lov-icon lov-icon-color">favorite</i>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event) and [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event) events instead.

> `mouseleave` and `mouseout` are similar but differ in that `mouseleave` does
>   not bubble and `mouseout` does. This means that `mouseleave` is fired when
>   the pointer has exited the element and all of its descendants, whereas
>   `mouseout` is fired when the pointer leaves the element or leaves one of
>   the element's descendants (even if the pointer is still within the
>   element).

```js
const applyMouseEnterStlye = (button, icon) => {
  button.removeClass('fav-btn');
  button.addClass('fav-btn-selected');
  icon.removeClass('lov-icon-color');
  icon.addClass('lov-icon-color-selected');
};
const applyMouseLeaveStlye = (button, icon) => {
  button.removeClass('fav-btn-selected');
  button.addClass('fav-btn');
  icon.removeClass('lov-icon-color-selected');
  icon.addClass('lov-icon-color');
};
const toggleStyles = event => {
  const button = $(event.target);
  const icon = $(button.find('i'));
  switch (event.type) {
    case 'mouseenter':
      applyMouseEnterStlye(button, icon);
      break;
    case 'mouseleave':
      applyMouseLeaveStlye(button, icon);
      break;
  }
}

const circleEl = document.querySelector('.circle');
circleEl.addEventListener('mouseenter', toggleStyles);
circleEl.addEventListener('mouseleave', toggleStyles);
```

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50% !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50% !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: -2px 3px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.circle>.icons {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  /* 50% - 3/4 of icon height */
}

.fav-btn {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.msg-btn {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.lov-icon {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.msg-icon {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.lov-icon-color {
  color: red;
}

.msg-icon-color {
  color: green;
}

.fav-btn-selected {
  background-color: #b61825;
}

.msg-btn-selected {
  background-color: green;
}

.lov-icon-color-selected {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.msg-icon-color-selected {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<a href="">
  <div class="circle fav fav-btn m-2">
    <i class="material-icons fav icons lov-icon lov-icon-color">favorite</i>
  </div>
</a>
```